# Anylogic Database - How To A Get List Of Column Headings?

Tags: sql, database, header, anylogic

I want to pass an Anylogic Database table name to a function, and within the function derive a list of the column headings for that table.  Otherwise it looks like I would need to pass a list of those headings to the function as well, which seems a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are passing table1 as parameter..just use the following query to get the column list..

Select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='table1'

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an answer more tailored to AnyLogic, even though the SQL command given by @Deependra is correct:

In your function you will have an argument of type String called tableName...
You will call the function using something like `function("table1");`

Then in your function you will collect the names of the columns with this:

```
List <String> columnNames= selectValues("Select column_name from
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name='"+tableName.toUpperCase()+"'");
```

You will get an additional column that holds the ID, but i guess it doesn't matter... you can just ignore the first element of columnNames list.